# Get per packet RSSI using libnltiny in Openwrt

Tags: openwrt, rssi

I am trying to find the RSSI of a packet on Openwrt. I found using libnl library - iw command which can be used for the same. I have already reserached on iwconfig and how it is obsolete. Now Openwrt supports only libnltiny which has only genl family of libnl. What I am trying to do is get RSSI per packet and store it in some database using C. For that I also found that I can make it event based using  enum ieee80211_event_type {RSSI_EVENT,  MLME_EVENT, };. I have all theoritical info about the topic but not sure about how to write specific code for this.  I have seen examples of code on how to establish a socket etc but how to get this particular info is not clear. Can anyone point out to code written for this or documentation on which structure has RSSI value and functions to access it. Please let me know if any more info is required

I am already referring infradead.org, stackoverflow and man pages for this

Thanks for all the help.